# query exclude a particular id altogether if a case is true

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm trying to figure out how to exclude a particular id altogether if i find a case is true. For example, if id_1 is in a row with column name called "joe" as well as in a row with a name called "bob", if I find that id_1 and "joe" are associated i don't want to return id_1 in my results regardless if it's associated with bob. How do I go about it?

Comment: `where columnname <> 'id_1'`

Comment: Do you want to filter the whole row with 'id_1' and 'joe', or just filter the value 'id_1'  in such rows (replace it with NULL)?

Answer (score 0):

You would use a `where` clause:

```
where not (id_1 = <value> and name = 'joe')
```

You can also express this as:

```
where id_1 <> <value> or name <> 'joe'
```

The logic is slightly more complicated if the columns can contain `NULL` values.